# Restructuring JavaScript array of objects in the most efficient way

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects who all share keys with the same name, `products`... I am having trouble bringing all of the values under the first `products` key, and removing the other two `products` keys.  I have tried various methods using `unshift()`, but keep messing it up.  What's the most efficient and simple way to restructure the array.

What it looks like now:

```
[ { products:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ] },
  { products:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ] },
  { products:
     [ [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object],
       [Object] ] } ]
```

What it should look like

```
[ { products: [Object], [Object], etc...
```

Comment: Your desired output is not valid JavaScript syntax. So that is just not possible. Inside the braces of an object literal you should have key/value pairs. Maybe you forgot a pair of `[ ]` somewhere...

Comment: @trincot , thanks, there was some syntax issues, as well as technical issues resolved below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your desired output is wrongly formatted, but from the description I get you want one array with product objects. I don't think it is necessary then to still have that joined array in an object, which again sits in an array with just that one object.

So, just make it one array, and assign it to a `products` variable. You can use `flatMap` for this:

```js
let arr = [
    { products: [{a: 1}, {b: 2}] },
    { products: [{c: 3}, {d: 4}] },
    { products: [{e: 5}, {f: 6}] }
];

let products = arr.flatMap(({products}) => products);

console.log(products);

// If you REALLY need it in an array with one object:
let obese = [{products}];
console.log(obese);
```

Comment: Amazing, thanks! I didn't know about flatMap(), I had been trying all sorts of ways to destructure the array using an iterator and push() or unshift() to build a new array.  This is much smoother (and works). It has fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Since your desired output is not valid JavaScript, I extrapolated a valid syntax:

```
const ary = [{products: ['a', 'b', 'c']}, {products: ['m', 'n']}, {products: ['x', 'y']}];

const result = {products: ary.reduce((accum, obj) => [...accum, ...obj.products], [])};

console.log(result) // output => {products: ['a', 'b', 'c', 'm', 'n', 'x', 'y']}
```